# Copy RichText (Formatted) To clipboard Java

Tags: java, string, fonts, clipboard

Using the following code to copy a flat string to (windows) System Clipboard:

```
StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(string);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
```

However this will only copy the text, Is there a why a string can be copied to the clipboard with formatting(RTF), so when pasted into another program e.g MS Word, the formatting is picked up?

(By formatting I mean for instance font, font size)

For example, I wish to copy the String : "Summary: Move waypoints to the left" in font size 12 Arial Font to the clipboard

Comment: A `Transferable` can have one or more `DataFlavor`s, you need to ascertain a data flavour which would be suitable, something like `text/html` (mimetype) for example

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966974/copy-jtable-row-with-its-grid-lines-into-excel-word-documents/24978019#24978019) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281679/copying-defaulttablemodel-data-to-clipboard/15283824#15283824)